# Adding an observer to each view or present view dynamically

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios4

I am posting a notification locally in the app when ever I receive a remote notification.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    NSLog(@"Received notification: %@", userInfo);
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NEWMESSAGE" object:nil userInfo:userInfo]; }
```

I have added an observer to the view in the  function viewWillAppear() and remove the observer in viewWillDisappear().

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(newMessageReceived:) name:@"NEWMESSAGE" object:nil];

and
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

My question is I want to override every viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear functions in all *.m files that use these functions in my app.

or how can I dynamically add an observer (like above) to the present view and remove the observer when that view disappears. it should be like a global action whenever view changes observer to be added and removed when it changes again.

Is this possible? if so please guide me.

thanks in advance.

Comment: as you mentioned you want to override viewwillappear and viewwilldisappear functions in each controller, do that and add and remove observer in that..than what's the problem.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.What you want to do? And what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some thoughts:

- You can subclass UIViewController and implement these method in the subclass-ed view controller class. Then you need to create all your views as the subclass of this UIViewController.

Example:

```
//Creating a custom subclass of UIViewController
@interface CustomViewController : UIViewController
@end

@implementation CustomViewController

 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(newMessageReceived:) name:@"NEWMESSAGE" object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

@end
```

And create all your view controller as the subclass of `CustomViewController`.

Comment: @VardhanDG: With pleasure :) All the best :)